# "Modified" spherical coordinates boundaries

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Assume I want to calculate the volume of an ellipsoid $ \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}}=1 $.

I know that the answer should be $abc$ times the volume of a unit sphere. Now using the following modified spherical coordinates:

$ x=ar\sin\theta\cos\varphi,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace y=br\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace z=cr\cos\theta $

I found the Jacobian would be $abc$. Im having trouble with understanding the new boundries; if it was a regular sphere, I know the bounderies would be $ 0\leq\theta\leq\pi,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace0\leq\varphi\leq2\pi,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace0\leq r\leq1 $.

And in order to get the right result from the triple integral, I noticed that the boundaries remain the same, even though this is now exactly the regular spherical coordinates.

So my questions are:

1. How can I determine for sure the boundaries? is there an explanation for why the boundaries are supposed to remain the same?

2.Is there a way to calculate this integral with the regular spherical coordinates? (I guess that the boundaries would be the problem once again).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, actually begin by writting your triple integral and write $r=f(\theta,\phi)$ in order to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the variable changes $u=\frac xa $, $v=\frac yb  $ and $w=\frac zc $ convert the ellipsoid $ \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}}=1 $ to a unit sphere
$u^2+v^2+w^2=1$ and the volume integration becomes

$$V=\iiint_{ellipsoid}dxdydz=abc\iiint_{unit\>sphere} dudvdw\\
=abc\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta \phi=\frac{4\pi}3 abc
$$